# Databricks -Cannot create table The associated location is not empty and also not a Delta table

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

I am getting the error:

> Cannot create table ('`hive_metastore`.`MY_SCHEMA`.`MY_TABLE`'). The
> associated location
> ('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/my_schema.db/my_table') is not empty and
> also not a Delta table.

I tried to overcome this by running

```
drop table 'hive_metastore`.`MY_SCHEMA`.`MY_TABLE`
```

But then I am getting

> [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view
> `hive_metastore`.`MY_SCHEMA`.`MY_TABLE` cannot be found. Verify the
> spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.

How Can I overcome that and recreate the table the that name in that location?
I already tried `create of *replace* table` but still getting the original error
`location is not empty`

Answer (score 1):

If the table exists, you can drop it using the following command:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hive_metastore.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE;

If the table does not exist, you can create it using the following command:

CREATE TABLE hive_metastore.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE () USING DELTA LOCATION 'dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/my_schema.db/my_table';

If you still get the same error, you can delete the contents of the location associated with the table using the following command:

dbutils.fs.rm('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/my_schema.db/my_table', True)

After deleting the contents of the location, you can try to create the table again using the above command.

Please see the below threads for your reference.

[Databricks - is not empty but it's not a Delta table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551620/databricks-is-not-empty-but-its-not-a-delta-table)

https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/error-the-associated-location-is-not-empty-but-it-s-not-a-delta/m-p/7430#M3314